# passing variable from one to another function

Tags: objective-c, variables

I have a problem.. i want to pass the selected segmentet index variable from this function:

```
-(IBAction)segControllIndex:(id)sender {

    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
   int segValue = [segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex];
```

to here:

```
 NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
 @"http://phpFile.php?Name=%1@&Artist=%2@&Titel=%3@&Genere=%4@", 
 insertName,insertArtist,insertTitle, PASSED VALUE];
```

i tryed so many things but i havend success..
Can you help me?

Thanks so much...

Comment: passed value is int..so use %d, write full function that u tried.

Comment: Read the basics of Objective-C, as this is straight-forward. Even your first method passes in a parameter (sender)...

Comment: i want to pass the segValue to the other function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming genre is supposed to be the integer, and assuming `insertName`, `insertArtist`, and `insertTitle` are instances of `NSString`:

```
// define this method in your class
-(void)someMethod:(int)passedValue {
    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://phpFile.php?Name=%@&Artist=%@&Titel=%@&Genere=%d", insertName,insertArtist,insertTitle, passedValue];

    // do your work
}
```

This way, you can call:

```
-(IBAction)segControllIndex:(id)sender {
    // I would recommend validating 'sender' first
    // withou knowing anything else about your calls, here is one example
    if ( [sender isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]] ) {
        UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
        int segValue = [segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex];

        [self someMethod:segValue];
    }
}
```

I would recommend [reading up on how to format `NSString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html), a [primer on Objective C methods and messaging](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/).

Comment: your last example help me very much at an other part.. thank you!

Comment: @CarstenGraf Glad I was that clever.